# Buff out tiny scratches on windshield?

Tags: windshield, scratch

The windshield of my car has, over the years, acquired a layer of tiny, tiny micro scratches. No more or less than any other car of the same age. It is still perfectly safe and comfortable to drive, it only looks a bit ugly when driving into the sun.

Is there a relatively straightforward way to buff/polish out these mini scratches? Either DIY, or for say 100-200€ at some shop? Or would that require either an immense amount of work, or a new windshield straight away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the short answer is "No", get a new windshield. I tried polishing out a tiny scratch once; I had availability of most/all grades of diamond polishing compounds , and silicon carbide and alumina. I gave up fairly quickly.

Comment: Mmh. I googled a bit, and it looks like getting a new windshield is, including time&material, absurdly inexpensive in my country. For whatever reason. Seems like they are pretty simple to change.

Answer (score 0):

Small scratches are easier to burnish rather than grind out. Grinding glass smooth is a complex process.

You can burnish glass by loading up a pad with rock salt and then rubbing against the glass. One type of pad that potentially work is that dark packing foam that that looks like lava. You need a really porous pad, like a sponge, to hold the salt crystals. You have to rub hard.